# updating multiple columns in the pandas data frame based another table

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science

I have 2 CSV file  like this , want to update the df1 columns (LL,UL) base on the df2(LL,UL) by matching columns (test ,cond) in the both dataframes
**df1:**

```
test Cond day  mode LL UL  
a    T1   Tue  7  
b    T2   mon  7  
c    T2   sun  6  
d    T3   fri  3  
c    T2   sat  6  
d    T3   wed  3
```

**df2:-**

```
test Cond LL   UL  
a    T1   15   23  
b    T2   -3   -3.5  
c    T2   -19  -11  
d    T3   6.5  14.5
```

my expected output should be:-

[image]

```
def SpecsLL(cond1,test1):
if ((cond1==spec['Cond'] ) & (test1==spec['test'])):
    return df2['LL']
df1['LL'] = df1.apply(lambda x: SpecsLL(x['Cond'],x['test']),axis=1)
```

i have tried above code but not working.
any ideas on how to do it??

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas Merging 101](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53645882/pandas-merging-101)

Answer (score 0):

### Method 1: `combine_first`

```
index_cols = ['test', 'Cond']
(
    df1
    .set_index(index_cols)
    .combine_first(
        df2.set_index(index_cols)
    ).reset_index()
)
```

Explanation:

- `set_index` moves the specified columns to the index, indicating that each row should be identified by its `test` and `Cond` columns.
- `foo.combine_first(bar)` will identify matching index + column labels between `foo` and `bar`, and fill in values from `bar` wherever `foo` is NaN or has a column/row missing. In this case, thanks to the `set_index`, the two dataframes will have their rows matched where `test` and `Cond` are the same, and then the `UL` and `LL` values from `df2` will be filled in to the corresponding columns of the output.
- `reset_index` simply reverses the `set_index` call, so that `test` and `Cond` become regular columns again.

Note that this operation might mangle the order of your columns, so if that is important to you then you can call `.reindex(df1.columns, axis=1)` at the very end, which will reorder the columns to original order in `df1`.

### Method 2: `merge`

Alternatively you can use the `merge` method, which allows you to operate on the columns directly without using `set_index`, but will require some other preprocessing:

```
index_cols = ['test', 'Cond']
(
    df1
    .drop(['LL', 'UL'], axis=1)
    .merge(
       df2,
       on=index_cols
    )
)
```

The `.drop` call is necessary because otherwise `merge` will include the `UL` and `LL` columns from both DataFrames in the output:

```
  test Cond  day  mode  LL_x  UL_x  LL_y  UL_y
0    a   T1  Tue     7   NaN   NaN  15.0  23.0
1    b   T2  mon     7   NaN   NaN  -3.0  -3.5
2    c   T2  sun     6   NaN   NaN -19.0 -11.0
3    c   T2  sat     6   NaN   NaN -19.0 -11.0
4    d   T3  fri     3   NaN   NaN   6.5  14.5
5    d   T3  wed     3   NaN   NaN   6.5  14.5
```

### Which to use?

With the data that you have provided, `merge` seems like the more natural operation - if you *never* expect UL and LL to have any data in `df1`, then if possible I'd recommend simply removing those column headers entirely from the input CSV, so that `df1` doesn't have those columns at all. In that case, the `drop` call would no longer be necessary and the required `merge` call is very expressive.

However, if you expect that `df1` would sometimes have real values for `UL` or `LL`, and you want to include those values in the output, then the `combine_first` solution is what you want. Note that if both `df1` and `df2` have different non-null values for a particular row/column, then the `df1.combine_first(df2)` will select the value from `df1` and ignore the `df2` value. If you instead wanted to prioritise the values from `df2` then you want to call it the other way round, i.e. `df2.combine_first(df1)`.

Comment: iam not able to replicate your output, i used same code

Comment: above both solutions , not giving expected output

Comment: @jagank can you post a code snippet to show exactly how you are constructing your inputs

Comment: figured out how to update the one table based on another table, i used loops by comparing the columns , Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Simply use merge functionalities of pandas

```py
df1.merge(df2)
```